# How to expose lamba endpoint in serverless.yml only for dev stage?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'd like to have a debug endpoint available only for stage. One way to do it is to the authorization in server code, but it would be even better not to create the API Gateway endpoint all together. Is it possible to achieve using Serverless framework?

Answer (score 1):

In Serverless Framework, you can use a switch based on your environment to toggle configuration options, within the context of your YAML file.

---

For example, if you wanted to setup a normal HTTP endpoint via API Gateway you'd add something like the following to your `functions` section:

```
functions:
  ping:
    handler: "src/functions/ping/handler.main"
    events:
      http:
        method: "any"
        path: "/ping"
```

If you want this `http` event to be available for only a certain stage, you can define a block elsewhere and reference it based on the current stage name. It's commonplace to use the `custom` block in your `serverless.yml` file for this. To isolate between the stages `prod` and `dev`, with `dev` being your staging area you'd do this:

```
custom:
  pingEvents: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
    prod:
      http:
        method: "any"
        path: "/ping"
    dev:
      http:

functions:
  ping:
    handler: "src/functions/ping/handler.main"
    events: "${self:custom.pingEvents.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}"
```

The above would only expose the endpoint via HTTP when you run `sls deploy --stage dev` to release your application; any other stage (e.g. – `prod`) will have it disabled. Do note, that in this example, if you want to support stages outside of `dev` and `prod` you'll need to add a new block under `custom.pingEvents`.